# SQL: Recursive query for path to find predecesssors and successors

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

Hello after creating a SQL database in the following way:

```
Create table kante (v int, n int);
INSERT INTO kante (n,v) VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO kante (n,v) VALUES (2,6);
```

I want to see the start and end of the path. However, the following does not work:

```
WITH RECURSIVE pfad (v,n) as ((SELECT v,n from kante) 
UNION ALL (Select k.V, p.N FROM Kante k, pfad p WHERE k.N=p.V)) 
SELECT * FROM pfad;
```

Also see the code at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/144162/4

Using SQLFiddle it produces the result:

> DDL and DML statements are not allowed in the query panel for MySQL; 
>   only SELECT statements are allowed.  Put DDL and DML in the schema
>   panel.

What do I have to do differently?

Thank you!

Comment: 5.6 doesn't support CTE

Comment: So which SQL online editor can I use that supports this?

Comment: My guess would be a non-MySQL one